# publish does not show resource groups

Tags: visual-studio-2019, azure-resource-group

I am trying to publish a project to azure. I want to re-use a web app. But I don't see the parent Resource group eve. Any ideas? Here is a picture:
[missing rg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f44Qd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be for different reason. but that happen to me was that the Azure web app resources that I created in AZURE was configured with a different NET framework that the application that I was trying to publish. In this case don't see the Web App and also not resource group.
Go to Azure portal and take a look to your WEB APP framework configuration at:

[image]

Change it to your use net framework if it is different.

Comment: Thanks freedeveloper,
Lately I switched to open source (no  .net framework )